# Database failure. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details. sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new sugarcrm developer i will configure sugarcrm in my localhost.

- I have install successfully but some existing module builder
  configuration not working

> error "Database failure.Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details".

In `sugarcrm.log` there was this message:

> Tue Aug 22 06:43:09 2017 [4546][1][FATAL] Query Failed: SELECT contacts_users_1contacts_ida id FROM contacts_users_1_c WHERE contacts_users_1_c.contacts_users_1users_idb = '1' AND contacts_users_1_c.deleted=0: MySQL error 1146: Table 'sugarcrm.contacts_users_1_c' doesn't exist

How to resolve that issue?

Comment: Tue Aug 22 06:43:09 2017 [4546][1][FATAL]  Query Failed: SELECT contacts_users_1contacts_ida id FROM contacts_users_1_c  WHERE contacts_users_1_c.contacts_users_1users_idb = '1' AND contacts_users_1_c.deleted=0: MySQL error 1146: Table 'sugarcrm.contacts_users_1_c' doesn't exist

Comment: That error seems quite clear to me; you haven't created the table yet.

Answer (score 0):

search your custom code where you wrote this query because this **is not default table of SugarCRM**. You have created it via customization therefore just comment out that query and then execute quick repair and rebuild. Execute any database mismatch query at the end of repair and rebuild page. Which might generate query for the creation of table with required schema.

Once table is created then uncomment your code and try again.